# android.osnetworkonmainthreadexception even if I have AsyncTask

Tags: android, http, networking, android-asynctask

I had followed this tutorial to implement crud php mysql android application
but when I excecuted the android project and I click on one item from the list of products 
I have this error :

```
android.osNetworkOnMainthreadException
```

here is the asynctask doinbackground :

```
 protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // Check for success tag
                int success;
                try {
                    // Building Parameters
                    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));

                    // getting product details by making HTTP request
                    // Note that product details url will use GET request
                    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                            url_product_detials, "GET", params);

                    // check your log for json response
                    Log.d("Single Product Details", json.toString());

                    // json success tag
                    success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                    if (success == 1) {
                        // successfully received product details
                        JSONArray productObj = json
                                .getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCT); // JSON Array

                        // get first product object from JSON Array
                        JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);

                        // product with this pid found
                        // Edit Text
                        txtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
                        txtPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPrice);
                        txtDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputDesc);

                        // display product data in EditText
                        txtName.setText(product.getString(TAG_NAME));
                        txtPrice.setText(product.getString(TAG_PRICE));
                        txtDesc.setText(product.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION));

                    }else{
                        // product with pid not found
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        return null;
    }
```

I removed runOnUithread but it generate me an other error

how can fix this issue

Comment: runOnUiThread -> NetworkOnMainthreadException.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the runOnUiThread.

Remove this code:

```
                    txtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
                    txtPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPrice);
                    txtDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputDesc);

                    // display product data in EditText
                    txtName.setText(product.getString(TAG_NAME));
                    txtPrice.setText(product.getString(TAG_PRICE));
                    txtDesc.setText(product.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION));
```

And add it to onPostExecute but you will have to edit your asynctask to return the object `product` and to use it in onPostExecute.

A very fast solution would be to put the code I mentioned above in runOnUiThread.

Comment: thank you, Sherif, I just put the code you have mentioned above in runOnUiThread and it works

Comment: Yes but the right way would be to change your Asynctask to `AsyncTask<String, WHATEVER, JsonObject>`. Then in doInBackgroud, you should return `product`. In `onPostExecute`, (instead of doInBackground), you can use the above code without runOnUiThread

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do runOnUiThread inside `doInBackground()` as you just need to display Product details, which You can straight way do it inside `onPostExecute()`.

Try below steps:

1. Return product JSONObject from `doInBackground()`.
2. Get JSONObject inside onPostExecute() and get whatever details you want from it. Now you can write code for displaying and updating UI code here in `onPostExecute()`:

> ```
>  txtName.setText(product.getString(TAG_NAME));
>  txtPrice.setText(product.getString(TAG_PRICE));
>  txtDesc.setText(product.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION));
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Do split your job.

1. Remove runOnUiThread from doInbackground and let it make the httpRequest and parse the response and return the response.
2. use onPostExecute to update the ui as per the response.